# High speed XSLT to convert from XML to CSV

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, transform, xslt-1.0

I have been trying to get CSV data from an XML document in most efficient time using XSLT. 
Following is my sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <sObjects xmlns="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
     <sObject>
        <Name>Raagu</Name>
        <BillingStreet>Hoskote</BillingStreet>
</sObject>
     <sObject>
        <Name>Rajath</Name>
         <BillingStreet>BTM</BillingStreet>
         <age>25</age>
</sObject>
     <sObject>
        <Name>Sarath</Name>
         <BillingStreet>Murgesh</BillingStreet>
         <location>Bangalore</location>
         <age>#N/A</age>
</sObject>
     <sObject>
         <Name>Bharath</Name>
         <BillingStreet>EGL</BillingStreet>
         <location>Bangalore</location>
             <shipping>Hoskote</Shipping>
</sObject>
     <sObject>
         <Id>12312321321</Id>
         <Name>Guru</Name>
         <location>Sirsi</location>
         <date>12-12-12</date>
</sObject>
     <sObject>
         <Name>Appa</Name>
         <BillingStreet>someStrrt</BillingStreet>
         <accountNo>213213</accountNo>
</sObject>
           <sObject>
          <Name>Sarath</Name>
          <BillingStreet>Murgesh</BillingStreet>
         <location>Bangalore</location>
</sObject>
     <sObject>
          <Name>Sarath</Name>
         <BillingStreet>Murgesh</BillingStreet>
          <location>Bangalore</location>
</sObject>
     <sObject>
          <Name>Sarath</Name>
          <BillingStreet>Murgesh</BillingStreet>
           <location>Bangalore</location>
</sObject>
```

and I wanted Output of this kind

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><csv xmlns="http://www.approuter.com/schemas/RootNode"><data>Name,BillingStreet,age,location,Shipping,Id,date,accountNo
Raagu,Hoskote,,,,,,
Rajath,BTM,25,,,,,
Sarath,Murgesh,#N/A,Bangalore,,,,
Bharath,EGL,,Bangalore,Hoskote,,,
Guru,,,Sirsi,,12312321321,12-12-12,
Appa,someStrrt,,,,,,213213
Sarath,Murgesh,,Bangalore,,,,
Sarath,Murgesh,,Bangalore,,,,
Sarath,Murgesh,,Bangalore,,,,</data></csv>
```

To get this done, I have tried following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:p0="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8"  method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:key name="field" match="p0:sObject/*" use="name()"/>

<!-- variable containing the first occurrence of each field -->
    <xsl:variable name="allFields"
    select="/*/*/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('field', name())[1])]"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Output the CSV header -->
        <xsl:element name="csv" namespace="http://www.approuter.com/schemas/RootNode">
            <xsl:element name="data" namespace="http://www.approuter.com/schemas/RootNode">

                <xsl:for-each select="$allFields">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
                    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>

                <xsl:text>&#xa;    </xsl:text>

                <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/p0:sObject" />

            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p0:sObject">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
        <xsl:for-each select="$allFields">
            <xsl:value-of select="$this/*[name() = name(current())]" />
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
            <xsl:text>&#xa;    </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT works really well from functioanality point of view.
But I am trying this to process around 10000 records. i,e 10000  instances on sObject elements each sObject will contain around 15 fields under it.

If I run this above XSLT to process these many records, it is going for toss. XSLT is taking around 20 minutes to process and giving csv data. I wanted to get this done within seconds. That is XSLT should take between 3-4 seconds to process 10k records (sObject entries) to give valid CSV data as shown above.

This is where I am stuck to enhance the XSLT and need help in modifying this XSLT to work faster.

Comment: Which xslt processor are you using?

Comment: Using XSLT 2.0 and saxon processor

Comment: Not sure if you already found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506348/how-do-i-know-my-xsl-is-efficient-and-beautiful)

Comment: Thansk @rene for link. Can you help me modify this XSLT to use 2.0 functionalities and use best coding to do the same. ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. If you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor, don't set version="1.0". That makes it run in backwards compatibility mode, which involves more run-time checking.
2. This kind of code, which occurs thrice in your stylesheet

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="$allFields">
       <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
       <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
           <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
       </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```

   is always better done by inserting a delimiter before an item if position()!=1 rather than after an item if position()!=last(). That's because last() is an expensive operation involving lookahead. In simple cases like this though, the whole thing can be replaced by

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="$allFields/name()" separator="{$delimiter}"/>
   ```
3. There's no point in defining a key if you're only going to use it once. Finding the unique field names is best done using `distinct-values(/*/*/*/name())`.

However, I really can't see any reason why this should take 20 minutes, and I don't think I've identified what the real problem is.

Comment: I made a sample 150k-line input and it took just over 20 seconds, nowhere near the 20 minutes. Idk either.

Comment: @Michael Kay Thanks for helping me understand some of the great points. I tried with your suggestions and little modifications. 
It works. Can you please help me get some more gyan on how exactly distinct-values() function works with respect to time complexity ? I read in w3schools regarding its functionalities. But I want to know more about how it works internally from performance point of view. For eg, If I have 10k instances of sObject elements each having 100 fields under it, and lets assume all sObject elements have same field names. In that case, how distinct-values() function works?

Comment: Does it intelligently finds unique fields names or does it parses each element ?

Comment: Obviously the way distinct-values works is implementation-dependent. But any sane implementation is likely to have performance that's essentially linear (or at worst O(n log n)) with the cost of evaluating its argument expression, which means in your case it's linear with the size of the document. There's no way this accounts for the 20minutes problem, at least not with Saxon.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a difficult problem. I didn't see anything obvious. Using a multi-step build is the trick: I created pass1.xsl and pass2.xsl which creates the output tree *much* faster.

I made a test file that had a tree size of 252097 nodes (697768 characters). Your XSL took 21sec and the below two xsls took a few seconds.

### Pass 1 XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:p0="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" 
    xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8"  method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:variable name="allFields">
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values( /*/*/*/name() )">
            <xsl:element name="{.}" />
        </xsl:for-each>    
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="p0:sObjects">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
            <xsl:element name="order" namespace="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
                <xsl:for-each select="$allFields/*">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
                    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/p0:sObject" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p0:sObject">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
            <xsl:for-each select="$allFields/*">
                <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$this/*[name() = name(current())]" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Pass 2 XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:p0="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" 
    xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8"  method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="csv" namespace="http://www.approuter.com/schemas/RootNode">
            <xsl:element name="data" namespace="http://www.approuter.com/schemas/RootNode">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/p0:sObjects/*" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p0:order">
        <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- use Michael's suggestion about using first instead of last() -->
    <xsl:template match="p0:sObject/*[ position() = 1 ]">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;    </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p0:sObject/*[ position() > 1 ]">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Pass 1 output

This is the output xml from pass 1. This would create an xml that looks like this (which is easier to parse for the next phase. See the new empty elements under sObject?):

```
<sObjects xmlns="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <order>Name,BillingStreet,age,location,shipping,Id,date,accountNo</order>
   <sObject>
      <Name>Raagu</Name>
      <BillingStreet>Hoskote</BillingStreet>
      <age/>
      <location/>
      <shipping/>
      <Id/>
      <date/>
      <accountNo/>
   </sObject>
</xObjects>
```

### Finally, the result:

```
<csv xmlns="http://www.approuter.com/schemas/RootNode"><data>Name,BillingStreet,age,location,shipping,Id,date,accountNo
    Raagu,Hoskote,,,,,,
    Rajath,BTM,25,,,,,
...
```

The command I executed:

```
saxonb-xslt -t bigxml.xml pass1.xsl > intermediate.xml
saxonb-xslt -t intermediate.xml pass2.xsl > res.xml
```

Comment: Thank u all. The solutions are superb.